# Devise Sign in button unresponsive once placed in an html container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, erb

I am trying to get a better understanding of how to join my front end and back end code in my rails application. I have created a VERY basic devise user, simply to practice applying the html and css. The sign up and log in work perfectly fine, until I add the html, then once in the container the sign in/sign up button becomes unresponsive. I can see it is being clicked, but nothing happens. I need heeeeeelp.

When I press the sign in button I get this in my server: I am not sure how to go about resolving that apparent routing error?

```
Started GET "/users/stylesheets/sign_in.css" for ::1 at 2020-09-08 15:48:12 +0200
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/stylesheets/sign_in.css"):
  
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:36:in `call'
web-console (4.0.4) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.0.4) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.4) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.0.4) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
webpacker (4.3.0) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
puma (4.3.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.6) lib/puma/server.rb:713:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.6) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.6) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

This is my sign-in code from views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
<link href="stylesheets/sign_in.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title>Pepperpeel | Sign In</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section class="container-fluid">
        <section class="row justify-content-center">
            <section class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <form class="form-container">
                <div class="form-group">
                <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                <%=image_tag("pepperpeel-logo-website.png", alt: "pepperpeel-logo-website")%>
                  <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
                  <h5>Looking to sign up?<a href="#"> Create an account here!</a></h5>
                  <%= f.label :email %><br />
                  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :password %><br />
                <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "current-password" %>
                  <h5><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></h5>
                </div>
                <%= f.submit"log in", class:"btn btn-primary btn-block" %>
                
              </form>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
<% end %>
</body>
</html>
```

Routs is simply:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  root 'pages#home'

   get 'sign_in', to: 'pages#sign_in'

end
```

As I said. Everything works until I plug in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO

The reason you're getting this is because rails expects for views and partials to only contain page related code and html (and css and js for that matter).  By adding the html base (this part)

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
      <link href="stylesheets/sign_in.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <title>Pepperpeel | Sign In</title>
    </head>
    <body>
```

Its reproducing what *should* be in the layout file.  There's a good medium post: https://medium.com/@kevinyckim33/rails-layout-rendering-cheatsheet-d40e14ab3503 but the gist is this:

Your app will have at least one, but probably more (one for each different situation) like this one

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

Inside that file you will have the kind of html code you posted. above, and then when you get the part (usually a wrapper or container div) where you want for the code from each page to display you'll add

```
<%= yield %>
```

In addition to a yield, where each rails view is added, you'll also add the csrf tag which is for security

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Now, if you want to have 2 different layouts, one for the users who are logged in and one for the login process, that's ok too.

Usually, you can tell each controller which layout file to use

```
    class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
      layout 'crazy_layout'
      def index
        @articles = Article.all
      end
    end
```

But for devise, if its using the controllers that come with the gem (it IS possible to override them but just in case you're not). you can also add the layout to the config.

```
config/initializers/devise.rb
```

By adding this to the existing config file

```
Devise::SessionsController.layout "layout_for_sessions_controller"
```

For more information on this you should check out the gem's wiki

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts